# Obtener el porcentaje de subida de un archivo sin Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, formularios, fileupload

Estoy intentando **obtener el porcentaje de subida de un archivo** enviado mediante un formulario normal, **sin Ajax**. Me aparece el porcentaje en la zona inferior izquierda del chrome, y lo que quiero es obtener ese porcentaje para usarlo en una barra de carga. No se ni si es posible ya que he buscado y no encuentro nada sin Ajax.

[image: Subiendo (33%)...]

Comment: Existe el evento progress de javascript este no depende de ajax, por lo que eso si es posible, pero deberás recordar entonces prevenir que se recargue la pagina al hacer submit.

Comment: Genial, la página no se recarga hasta que el archivo se ha subido por naturaleza, pero tal vez el javascript no funcione durante este proceso verdad?

Comment: Para nada, el javascript seguira funcionando igual, preventDefault solo nos ayuda a que no se recargue la pagina, pero de resto puedes ejecutar todo lo que desees donde hayas hecho el preventDefault sin problemas.